# Какой принцип работы в Shared Preferences?

Tags: android, ооп, android-sdk, android-shared-preferences

Если `SharedPreferences.Editor` это интерфейс, то как мы тогда делаем объект editor?

```
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREFS, MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
// some code
editor.apply();
```

Comment: а нельзя создать объект интерфейса? или обобщить дочерний объект родительским интерфейсом? вопрос непонятен и слегка абсурден.

Comment: Так `SharedPreferences` тоже интерфейс. Платформа реализует и то, и другое и предоставляет нам экземпляры своей реализации. Мы здесь ничего не создаём и не делаем - мы используем готовое, обобщённое интерфейсами.

Comment: Так откройте исходный код и ознакомьтесь

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Рассмотрим такой пример, пусть у вас есть интерфейс `Animal` и два класса, которые имплементируют этот интерфейс:

```java
interface Animal {}

class Cat implements Animal {}

class Dog implements Animal {}
```

Кроме этого, предположим, есть класс-фабрика `Animals` для создания экземпляров животных:

```java
class Animals {
    static Animal getInstance(String type) {
        switch (type) {
            case "cat":
                return new Cat();
            case "dog":
                return new Dog();
            default:
                throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
        }
    }
}
```

Теперь, когда вы создаете животных через фабрику, то вы можете и не знать, какими именно конкретными классами вы оперируете. Вы только видите, что создали какого-то `Animal` и работаете с ним, как с `Animal`:

```java
Animal animal = Animals.getInstance("cat");
```

Примерно то же самое и с `SharedPreferences`.